# Android/Firebase: Glide not working inside one of my fragments

Tags: java, android, firebase, fragment, android-glide

So I have an app with three fragments that I can switch through with tabs. One of the tabs/fragments is a "Feed" that contains pictures of users from a firebase database. The pictures are stored as links to Firebase storage items. Glide works perfectly fine in this fragment. I'm now trying to add a gallery feature in another tab/fragment using another RecyclerView which is almost identical to the feed tab, but it doesn't work.

Here is my onCreateView in my Gallery fragment:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.galleryRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // This list is populated by a Firebase childEvent listener 
        imageIDs = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new MyGalleryAdapter2(imageIDs);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Method that retrieves the images from the Firebase DB (works)
        getGalleryDB();

        return view;
    }
```

I have debugged and made sure that the ArrayList is populated with working image links (16 of them).

Here is my GalleryAdapter class:

```
public class MyGalleryAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyGalleryAdapter2.MyViewHolder> {

    List<String> images;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {   
            public ImageView imageView;   
            public MyViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);
                imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.gallery_image);
            }
    }

    public MyGalleryAdapter2(List<String> images){
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyGalleryAdapter2.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // This doesn't work
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(images.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);
       // holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallery_icon); This works for some reason
    }

    @Override
    public MyGalleryAdapter2.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {

        View v = (View) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, parent, false);

        MyGalleryAdapter2.MyViewHolder vh = new MyGalleryAdapter2.MyViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return images.size();
    }
}
```

In the "onBindViewHolder" method glide doesn't load the images into the ImageView for some reason. I tried debugging and the links are correct at that point. I also tried just setting the image resource to a local image and the RecyclerView is populated with 16 of these images (the amount of images retrieved from the database).

This issue 100% has something to do with Glide, but I just can't figure it out. Any help will be appreciated. I've been pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: Check your Context you use - holder.imageView.getContext(). If null then use holder context or Fragment context.

Comment: It isn't null. It has values.

Comment: You missed notifyDatasetChanged method to call.

Answer (score 2):

You write wrong code for Glide.

In Adapter you load image using this code

```
Glide.with(context).load(images.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);
```

In Fragment you load image using this code

```
 Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(myImageView);
```

Load Firebase image using this code

```
 FirebaseStorage u = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("photos/" + auth);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(u)
                    .into(ivm);
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing context from your fragment to your adapter and use that

Replace this        `Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load(images.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);`

with

```
Glide.with(context).load(images.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

For loading images using Glide, could you please try this one to load bitmap from firebase

```
 Glide.with(context)
      .load(images.get(position))
      .into(
          new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(
                @NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
              holder.imageView.set(resource);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
             //set placeholder if any
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical issue and it turned out to be not having internet permission in the manifest file. Adding the following line solved the problem:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```